# Find the line integral for the following vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

$\vec{G} = \big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}\big)$.
I need to calculate the line integral $\int_{\mathrm{CR}}\vec {G}\, d\vec{r}\, $ where $CR$ is a circle with the center in origin and the radius $1 \lt R.$
I know that $x^2+y^2 \gt 1,$ which means all points outside of the circle with radius $1$ and center in origin. How do you calculate the line integral of such a vector field?

Comment: Fun fact. If $G(x,y)=f\big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\big)\big<x,y\big>$ then $G=\nabla g$ where $$g(x,y)=\int_0^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}tf(t)dt$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can establish that $\vec G$ is conservative, meaning there is some scalar function $g(x,y)$ such that $\nabla g(x,y)=\vec G$. In particular, you have

$$g(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}+c$$

since

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}\\[1ex]
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}
\end{cases}$$

where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. Then by the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem), the line integral over the given curve is $0$.

Comment: Green's Theorem doesn't apply here; $C_R$ encloses a disc of radius $R>1$ cenetered around $(0,0)$ in which $G$ doesn't have continuous partials derivatives.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Ah, you're right, I've removed that part. (Though, that Green's theorem gave the same conclusion is a happy coincidence.)